# TypeError when using Drilldown module in Highcharts React Official

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to create a Pie chart with a drilldown, but whenever I try to run the chart with the Drilldown module imported and attached to the Highcharts object (like in the highcharts-react-official documentation), I get this following error.

[image: Example of error introduced by using Highcharts Drilldown]

```
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Core/Animation/AnimationUtilities.js')
```

I am unsure how this is happening. If I comment out the drilldown information then it renders (without drilldown of course). Any idea what I can do?

```js
import React, { useState, FC, ReactElement, useRef } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import highchartsDrilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown';

highchartsDrilldown(Highcharts);

type Props = {};

// https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown
const MonthlyBreakdown: FC = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
  const chartComponentRef = useRef<HighchartsReact.RefObject>(null);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<Highcharts.Options>({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
    },
    credits: { enabled: false },
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Breakdown',
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Click slices to drilldown into the data',
    },
    accessibility: {
      announceNewData: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      point: {
        valueSuffix: '%',
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%',
        },
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
      pointFormat:
        '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>',
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Monthly',
        type: 'pie',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Taxes',
            color: '#bf212f',
            custom: {
              amount: 2926.38,
            },
            y: 26.8,
            drilldown: 'taxes',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    drilldown: {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Taxes',
          type: 'pie',
          id: 'taxes',
          data: [
            {
              name: 'Federal Income Tax',
              y: 50,
              custom: {
                amount: 687.96,
              },
            },
            {
              name: 'Social Security Tax',
              y: 50,
              custom: {
                amount: 325.8,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
      ref={chartComponentRef}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export default MonthlyBreakdown;
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "learn-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "export": "npm run build && next export"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^0.15.4",
    "@next/mdx": "^10.0.7",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.21.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.2",
    "highcharts": "^9.3.2",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^2.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mdx-js__react": "^1.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.10",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: I reproduce your issue and everything seems fine on the online editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5jeemc?file=index.tsx Try to import HC in this way: `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';`

Comment: @SebastianWędzel tryign this out and will get back to you. Thanks for your reply